# How to add a select dropdown and populate it automatticly

Tags: php, mysql, ajax, logic

Ok, so heres my question. I have a select dropdown that is populated from my table, **category_names**. I am getting the id and the name and using the id as the value. And the name as the select name.

```
<?php
      include("./config.php");
      $query="SELECT id,name FROM category_names";
      $result = mysql_query ($query);
      echo "<strong>Pick as many that fit your business</strong><br/><br/>";
      echo"<div style='overflow:auto;height:300px;width:100%'><select>";
      // while loop
      while($nt=mysql_fetch_array($result)){//Array or records stored in $nt


      echo "<option value=NAME=$nt[id]>$nt[name]</option><br/>

";

      }?>
```

Ok so that populates my select. But now I want to hit a little "ADD" hyperlink at the bottom and another identical select dropdown to appear underneath that is also populated from my database. And each select needs to add to a different row in table. How do I achieve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simple function for populating selects on abstract array of values

```
<?php
function make_select($select_name,$select_vals,$name_of_key,$name_of_label){
    echo "<select name='".$select_name."'>";
    foreach($select_vals as $opt){
        echo "<option value=NAME=".$opt[$name_of_key].">".$opt[$name_of_label]."</option>";
    }
    echo "</select>";
}
?>
```

and you can call it like:

```
<?php
    $result_set = mysql_query('SELECT id_of_category,name FROM categories;');
    make_select('first_select',$mysql_fetch_assoc($result_set),'id_of_category','name');
    $result_set2 = mysql_query('SELECT id_of_product,title FROM products;');
    make_select('second_select',$mysql_fetch_assoc($result_set2),'id_of_product','title');
```

Comment: I'm sorry... I'm a noob to php...How do I work this into the code I already have? Or is this a completely new thing?

Comment: I've added some use-case, but it really depends on structure of DB you're using and system how your app works. Probably you want to learn some PHP Framework, where is this kind of things abstracted into frameworks abilities. Or you can learn and google more :)

Comment: Thanks! Do you have a personal favorite?

Comment: CakePHP ( http://www.cakephp.org/ ) is my favorite. It has plenty of documentation and many helpfull members (mainly on IRC channel freenode.net#cakephp )